# SQL between date range not as expected

Tags: sql-server-2008, between, date-range

if i have a DateStart = 2012-03-19 00:00:00.000  and a DateEnd of 2012-03-24 23:59:59.000  then i try

```
SELECT EventGuid,
       Title,
       DESCRIPTION,
       CONVERT(DATETIME, FLOOR(CONVERT(FLOAT, DateStart)))            AS
       DateStart,
       CONVERT(DATETIME, FLOOR(CONVERT(FLOAT, DateEnd))) + '23:59:59' AS DateEnd
       ,
       Address1,
       Address2,
       City,
       PostalCode,
       Country,
       Latitude,
       Longitude,
       SeatCount,
       SeatCost,
       Active,
       DateCreated,
       DATEPART(HH, DateStart)                                        AS
       StartHour,
       LastModified
FROM   Event
WHERE  ( Active = 1 )
       AND ( EventTypeGuid <> '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000' )
       AND ( CONVERT(DATETIME, '3/19/2012') <= DateEnd )
       AND ( CONVERT(DATETIME, '3/19/2012') >= DateStart )
ORDER  BY DateStart
```

It does not pick up the row.

If i alter to Between syntaxt

```
SELECT EventGuid,
       Title,
       DESCRIPTION,
       CONVERT(DATETIME, FLOOR(CONVERT(FLOAT, DateStart)))            AS
       DateStart,
       CONVERT(DATETIME, FLOOR(CONVERT(FLOAT, DateEnd))) + '23:59:59' AS DateEnd
       ,
       Address1,
       Address2,
       City,
       PostalCode,
       Country,
       Latitude,
       Longitude,
       SeatCount,
       SeatCost,
       Active,
       DateCreated,
       DATEPART(HH, DateStart)                                        AS
       StartHour,
       LastModified
FROM   Event
WHERE  ( Active = 1 )
       AND ( EventTypeGuid <> '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000' )
       AND ( CONVERT(DATETIME, '3/19/2012') BETWEEN DateStart AND DateEnd )
ORDER  BY DateStart
```

It also doesent get 3/19 date

So i then modified to the SQl below, DateStart=2012-06-03 23:59:51.000  DateStart2 (i need to display it) 2012-06-04 00:00:00.000 and DateEnd 2012-06-09 23:59:59.000   But it doesent pick up the 6/4 date...

```
SELECT EventGuid,
       Title,
       DESCRIPTION,
       CONVERT(DATETIME, FLOOR(CONVERT(FLOAT, DateStart))) - '00:00:09' AS
       DateStart,
       CONVERT(DATETIME, FLOOR(CONVERT(FLOAT, DateStart)))              AS
       DateStart2,
       CONVERT(DATETIME, FLOOR(CONVERT(FLOAT, DateEnd))) + '23:59:59'   AS
       DateEnd,
       Address1,
       Address2,
       City,
       PostalCode,
       Country,
       Latitude,
       Longitude,
       SeatCount,
       SeatCost,
       Active,
       DateCreated,
       DATEPART(HH, DateStart)                                          AS
       StartHour,
       LastModified
FROM   Event
WHERE  ( Active = 1 )
       AND ( EventTypeGuid <> '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000' )
       AND ( CONVERT(DATETIME, '6/4/2012') BETWEEN DateStart AND DateEnd )
ORDER  BY DateStart
```

Comment: Which sql database are you talking about?

Answer (score 0):

I was unable to solve the SQL query issue in the time i was willing to put into the issue.

I made my Between select query more generous:

```
BETWEEN DATEADD(DAY, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, DateStart), -1) AND DATEADD(DAY, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, DateEnd), +1))
```

And then handled the filtering in my vb.net code where it ws stable.

```
If (e.DayRenderInfo.Date >= dt.Rows(i).Item("DateStart")) And (e.DayRenderInfo.Date <= dt.Rows(i).Item("DateEnd")) Then
```